# AngularJS ng-view does not pass utf-8 encoding to nested pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, encoding, utf-8

My application contains an index.html page that looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyExample">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The ng-view div is then filled with different pages I store in another folder. As I am writing for a german speaking audience, I need to include special characters like ä, ö, or ü. However, these characters are only rendered correctly if written somewhere within the index.html page. As soon as they are to be displayed somewhere in a nested page of the ng-view div, they are represented as < ? >. It seems as if the utf-8 encoding is not passed on to the nested html files. I made sure the html files are also utf-8 encoded (I'm using eclipse for development and simply changed the properties of the file to utf-8). Does anybody know anything about this or how to solve it?

Comment: You have to use ng-bind-html


https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Okay, from what I see that sounds reasonable to some extent. However, I'm rather new to Angular so I'm not sure how to use it. Should I copy the code for all these html pages into their corresponding angular controller and generate it there? Or is there a way to include the whole html file?

Comment: Check this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/d0dgzav5/

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code using this alternative ?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem in Visual Studio and the solution was to save the file in the correct encoding -- in this case UTF-8.